# Android - Custom EditText with different input types

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm trying to make a custom `EditText` for currency which means I need to have a prefix of it for the currency and I have to limit users' input to numbers only.

This is my custom `EditText` code

```
public OpenSansEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    paint = getPaint();
    applyCustomFont(context, attrs);
}

public OpenSansEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    paint = getPaint();
    applyCustomFont(context, attrs);
}

private void applyCustomFont(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.OpenSansET);

    ...

    // Prefix
    String prefix = a.getString(R.styleable.OpenSansET_prefix);
    if (prefix != null) {
        mPrefix = prefix;
    } else {
        mPrefix = "";
    }

    // Prefix Color
    int prefixColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.OpenSansET_prefixColor, 0);
    if (prefix != null) {
        mPrefixColor = prefixColor;
    } else {
        mPrefixColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.miBlack);
    }

    a.recycle();
}

...
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    if (!mPrefix.equals("")) {
        getPaint().getTextBounds(mPrefix, 0, mPrefix.length(), mPrefixRect);
        mPrefixRect.right += getPaint().measureText(" "); // add some offset
    }

    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    if (!mPrefix.equals("")) {
        paint.setColor(mPrefixColor);
        canvas.drawText(mPrefix, super.getCompoundPaddingLeft(), getBaseline(), paint);
    }
}

@Override
public int getCompoundPaddingLeft() {
    return mPrefix.equals("") ? super.getCompoundPaddingLeft()
            : super.getCompoundPaddingLeft() + mPrefixRect.width();
}
```

This is how I use it in xml :

```
<com.asta.www.classes.OpenSansEditText
    android:id="@+id/shopping_filter_priceMinRange"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.4"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:hint="@string/min"
    android:textColor="@color/miBlack"
    android:textColorHint="@color/miGrey"
    app:prefix="$"
    app:prefixColor="@color/miBlack" />

<com.asta.www.classes.OpenSansEditText
    android:id="@+id/shopping_filter_priceMaxRange"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.4"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:hint="@string/max"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:textColorHint="@color/miGrey"
    app:prefix="$"
    app:prefixColor="@color/miBlack" />
```

Which yields :

[image: This]

Only the first one without `inputType` as `number` has the currency sign shown, whereas the second ET doesn't have its currency sign shown.

How to achieve currency prefix as text and still keeping `inputType` to numbers only for user? And I don't want to use two views, namely `EditText` and `TextView` to left of it, both inside a `ViewGroup` to achieve that.

Comment: How about using
`android:drawableLeft`
to achieve your goal? So you just simply put the sign icon as a left drawable of standard edittext, then you're free with any input type

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention that, it is not only used for currency and not only used for 1 currency, it's for prefix..

Answer (score 1):

For this type of scenarios I use Compound views. Please see below code for more information.

First create a layout for your custom view like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_prefix"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="$" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_value"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="number" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Now create a new class which should extends the LinearLayout. See below code.

```
public class OpenSansEditText extends LinearLayout {
    private TextView txtPrefix;
    private EditText etValue;
    private String prefix = "$";
    private int prefixColor = Color.BLACK;

    public OpenSansEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initializeViews(context, null);
    }

    public OpenSansEditText(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initializeViews(context, attrs);
    }

    public OpenSansEditText(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        initializeViews(context, attrs);
    }

    private void initializeViews(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.opensansedittext_view, this,true);

        if (attrs != null) {
            TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.OpenSansEditText);
            prefix = a.getString(R.styleable.OpenSansEditText_prefix);
            prefixColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.OpenSansEditText_prefixColor, Color.BLACK);
        }
    }

    public  CharSequence getValue(){
        return etValue.getText();
    }

    public CharSequence getPrefix(){
        return txtPrefix.getText();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();
        txtPrefix = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_prefix);
        etValue  = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_value);

        txtPrefix.setText(prefix);
        txtPrefix.setTextColor(prefixColor);
    }
}
```

And then add your attributes to attribute xml file Ex: (attrs.xml in my case)

```
<resources>

    <declare-styleable name="OpenSansEditText">
        <attr name="prefix" format="string"/>
        <attr name="prefixColor" format="color"/>
    </declare-styleable>

</resources>
```

Now you can use it anywhere in the project as below

```
  <com.asta.www.classes.OpenSansEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:prefix="$"
        app:prefixColor="#f00"/>
```

Hope this will help you to solve your problem. Thanks...

Comment: Wow! I found the answer by myself, but this is a good info! I didn't know about compound views like that, I was wondering though if there is anything like that, now you answered it! Hahaha.. My solution was to google deeper and I got a solution which uses the text supplied as drawable not text so it doesn't get affected by the inputType for user :D

Answer (score 0):

In the end I found this link https://gist.github.com/kennydude/5407963 which helps me in the right direction. So what it does is I think making the prefix as `Drawable` using this class :

```
private class TagDrawable extends Drawable {

    public String text = "";

    public void setText(String s){
        text = s;

        // Tell it we need to be as big as we want to be!
        setBounds(0,0,getIntrinsicWidth(),getIntrinsicHeight());

        invalidateSelf();
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(@NonNull Canvas canvas) {
        // I don't know why this y works here, but it does :)
        // (aka if you are from Google/are Jake Wharton and I have done it wrong, please tell me!)
        canvas.drawText( text, 0, mLine0Baseline + canvas.getClipBounds().top, mTextPaint );
    }

    @Override public void setAlpha(int i) {}
    @Override public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter colorFilter) {}
    @Override public int getOpacity() {return PixelFormat.UNKNOWN;}

    @Override public int getIntrinsicHeight (){
        return (int)mFontHeight;
    }
    @Override public int getIntrinsicWidth(){
        return (int)mTextPaint.measureText( text );
    }
}
```

And draw it to the left of the `TextView` like

```
TagDrawable left = new TagDrawable();
left.setText("$");
setCompoundDrawablesRelative(left, null, null, null);
```

The link I supplied even has suffix support which I haven't tried.